# ssh still active while port closed on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, port, aws-security-group

Why can I keep ssh open while closing all ports on an AWS EC2 instance?

I created an AWS EC2 instance with a security group and an ssh key for access.
In that security group I opened port 22 in inbound rules and `ssh ubuntu@<ip>` to that instance.
Now, I edit the security group and close all ports in inbound rules.
The `ssh` session is still active and I can still run commands on the EC2 instance.
Only when I exit and try to reconnect the instance ignores me.
Can somebody explain how that's possible?
So I can't cancel active ssh sessions by changing security groups?

Comment: The first rule of any firewall is usually to allow any already established TCP connections.

Comment: The AWS security groups deny everything by default. Then you can add rules for ports and ip ranges that should be accepted.

Comment: [Security groups are stateful](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules.html), once a connection is established, the TCP connection can send data either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [Security group connection tracking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-connection-tracking.html):

> When you change a security group rule, its tracked connections are not immediately interrupted. The security group continues to allow packets until existing connections time out.

Comment: Oh, that explains it. Good to know! I always thought they just immediately drop everything.

Comment: can you please verify if dropping on ssh starts after 600 seconds you modify the NSG? just curious...

Comment: I opened a ssh session in a terminal, then closed ports, and didn't touch that terminal. After 11m I did `ls` in that terminal, and it still worked. Does `ssh` maybe keep  itself alive by regularly sending something?

Comment: honestly, I don't know... potentially there will be a keepalive message, able to handle the communication up.

Comment: TIL security groups are not good for locking people out who potentially already have an active session

Comment: The 600 second timeout does not apply here since SSH connections, by default, send a TCPKeepAlive ping every 5 seconds to verify connectivity, this keeping the TCP connection itself from timing out.